# Reject array items by Ramda.js composite AND condition

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I would like to `reject` array items using `Ramda.js` library.

It's necessary to remove items, that has two props that equals to `0`.
Is it possible to do that `without lambdas` with plain `Ramda.js` functions?

I expect to receive items with `A, B, C` names (all except `D`, where `acc` and `bal` both equals to `0`), but my example returns `A, C`.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'A',
    acc: 1,
    bal: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    acc: 3,
    bal: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'C',
    acc: 0,
    bal: 4,
  },
  {
    name: 'D',
    acc: 0,
    bal: 0,
  }
]

const filteredItems = R.reject(
  R.and(
    R.propEq('acc', 0),
    R.propEq('bal', 0)
  )
)(arr)
```

This is [Ramda REPL to test my example](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20arr%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27A%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20acc%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20bal%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27B%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20acc%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20%20%20bal%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27C%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20acc%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20bal%3A%204%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27D%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20acc%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20bal%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0AR.reject%28%0A%20%20R.and%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.propEq%28%27acc%27%2C%200%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.propEq%28%27bal%27%2C%200%29%0A%20%20%29%0A%29%28arr%29)

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: R.without(
   R.filter(has_bal,R.filter(has_acc, arr)),arr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Ramda library, the `R.and` method returns a boolean, in contrast, the `R.reject` method expects an iterable to use in order to loop through the supplied array. You can achieve this by using the `R.allPass` method. This method takes an array of predicates (like `R.propEq`) and returns a predicate that combines them using the "AND" logic.

```
R.reject(
    R.allPass([
        R.propEq('acc', 0),
        R.propEq('bal', 0)
    ])
)(arr);
```

Note: if you want to use the "OR" logic, you can use `R.anyPass` instead.

Comment: If you only have two predicates to combine, you can also use [R.both](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#both) instead of `R.allPass`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using `R.allPass`/`R.both` with `R.propEq` is [`R.where`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#where), which takes a "spec object" and returns true if all properties are satisfied.

```
R.reject(R.where({
  acc: R.equals(0),
  bal: R.equals(0)
}))
```

Comment: This would be my choice for readability.  If you import the functions directly, and thus skip the `R` prefix, this reads really well in English: "Reject where `acc` equals `0`, `bal` equals `0`."   It's hard to beat this.